# continue displaying Jquery modal irrespective of page load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to jQuery.
I am trying to show a jQuery modal on Upload button click but this modal is immediately getting disappeared due to page load. I want the modal to disappear only after a button in the modal is clicked.
Please suggest how to continue displaying modal in jQuery irrespective of the page load.

jQuery:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#btnUpload", function () {
        $("#myModalInvalidRecords").modal("show");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Fund/GetInvalidRecords/",
            type: "post",
            success: function (res) {
                alert(res);
                $("#myModalInvalidRecords").modal("show");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            },
            async: false
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `return false` and `e.preventDefault();`  and stop the page load, since you are using `AJAX`. Below is the updated code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnUpload", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#myModalInvalidRecords").modal("show");
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Fund/GetInvalidRecords/",
    type: "post",
    success: function(res) {
      $("#myModalInvalidRecords").modal("show");
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error");
    },
    async: false
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the correct answer. It worked for me. :)

Comment: You’re welcome, If it helped you, please [upvote and accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Happy Coding! :)